# how force vagrant to create full clone instead of a linked clone when using vmware fusion

Tags: vagrant, vmware-fusion

i using vagrant 1.8.5 with vmware fusion 7.1.3

in the [documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/configuration.html) is a config variable for virtualbox to switch between full and linked clone.

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
   v.linked_clone = true
end
```

is there a vagrant config option for vmware fusion to use full clone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to answer my own question:
vagrant 1.9.3 allows you to disable linked clones with the vmware provider too. see the [documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vmware/configuration.html#linked-clones)

```
config.vm.provider "vmware_fusion" do |v|
  v.linked_clone = false
end
```